# I can't get rid of the double-header in my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, header

I have the following dataframe with an annoying 'Dates" heading hanging there that I want to get rid of:

[image: Dataframe]

If I reset the index using `df.reset_index(level='Dates', inplace=True)` I get the following.

[image]

As soon as I try and set the index again to the "Dates" column I get go back to a dataframe that looks like the first snapshot. `df_hist5.set_index(['Dates'], inplace=True)`

How do I get to a simple dataframe that looks as follows? I've tried multiple resets, deleting columns, everything else I can find online - all with no luck.

[image: Dataframe I want]

Comment: Use `rename_axis(columns=None)`

Comment: I reset the index and tried `rename_axis` which deleted "Date" from the index header.  But when I try reset the index to my "Dates" column I get a similar result to my first snapshot, except that "Date" is deleted but I still have a "Dates" sitting in that second row.